# Efficient Algorithm for finding MinMax of Quadratic Functions?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-forms, maxima-minima

Given a set of n quadratic functions

$f_i(x) = x^T A_i x + b_i^T x + c_i$

with $x\in R^m$, $i\in[0,n-1]$ and $\det A_i < 0$, that is each of the functions has a maximum.

I am looking for $x$ that maximises the minimum of these functions, that is

$\arg \max_x min_i f_i(x)$

I assume that the [MinMax Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem) doesn't apply because my functions $f_i$ are not convex, but concave because $\det A_i<0$.

In my specific application, the number of these functions $n$ can be in the thousands and the number of dimensions $m$ of the vector $x$ can be in the tens.

[Example for n=3 and m=1. The solution in this case is x=0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mevl.png)

Can somebody please recommend an efficient algorithm for solving this?

Comment: "Concave because $\det A_i<0$" is no good explanation. The determinant condition is not relevant here for concavity in general. If you **know** that all $f_i$ are concave then $\min_i f_i$ is concave too. Moreover, it is possible to rewrite the probem to make use of minimax in this case..

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Yes, I know that the functions are concave. Could you please give me a hint on how to rewrite the problem to make use of minimax in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce the probability simplex
$$
Y=\{y\in{\Bbb R}^n\colon \sum_{i=1}^ny_i=1,\ y_i\ge 0\}.
$$
Then 
$$
\min_{1\le i\le n}f_i(x)=\min_{y\in Y}\sum_{i=1}^n y_if_i(x)
$$
and the function
$$
F(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n y_if_i(x)
$$
satisfies all the conditions of minimax, in particular, convex in $y$ and concave in $x$.

To solve the problem, however, it seems appropriate to rewrite differently
$$
\min_i f_i(x)\ge\gamma\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad f_i(x)\ge\gamma,\quad\forall i
$$
that gives the following equivalent problem
$$
\max_{x,\gamma}\gamma\qquad\text{subject to } f_i(x)\ge\gamma,\ \forall i.
$$
This is a convex optimization problem with many different numerical algorithms being available.